# Does accepting multiple answers give points to each contribution?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

If I choose an accepted answer, then revert my choice and accept someone else's. Which one gets the 15+ reputation? Is it both? Or only the first?

Comment: Worth to mention, the one who had the accepted answer and "lost" it will see a -15 rep event so don't be surprised if you get a comment asking why you did it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only the last person.

The 15 reputation will be taken from the person whose accept was removed, and be given to the person who got the accept.

Comment: With the usual limits, i.e. no points if the it's a self answer or CW.